# Why will my friend have to grow his beard out?

Tags: wordplay, english

*Knowledge required for this riddle: English-language proverbs.*

My friend Leonard came to me with a problem the other day. He said, “Tanner, I want to have a clean-shaven face. But every time I use a razor, I end up with this nasty painful rash.”

“Razor burn,” I said.

“Yeah, that's right,” said Leonard. “Do you have any advice for me?”

“Unfortunately, there's no good solution,” I told him. “You're going to have to either grow your beard out, or just cope with those painful rashes.”

**Why will Leonard have to grow his beard out?**

Comment: Beacuse he who shaves all the barbers who do not shave themselves should never ask whether you need a haircut. I think that's how the proverb goes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Maybe it is because

> A Lenny shaved is a Lenny burned.
>  (A penny saved is a penny earned.)

Comment: Can whoever voted this down, explain why? My answer is an English proverb that through wordplay works as the reason for Leonard to grow his beard.

Comment: They probably were trying to downvote my answer and clicked yours instead.  ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀)

Comment: Looks like someone just went on a rampage and downvoted everything here.

Comment: Going to be honest, I'm using this version of the proverb from  now on.

Comment: Say, aren't you the author of Jaap's Puzzle Page? I fondly remember that page from when I was a kid, in the early 2000s. I'm honored to have you answer my riddle. :D

Comment: @TannerSwett Oh stop it, you're making me feel old. :-)

Comment: Is there any method to the transformation?

Comment: @jpmc26 No, just that words are replaced by ones that sound rather similar so you have a sentence with the same rhythm and similar sound to the original. There is a long tradition of this kind of joke, for example the rather out-dated "Squaw of the hippopotamus" maths joke.

Answer (score 13):

I hope I'm not even close, but maybe...

> A Leo<sup>1</sup>-pard<sup>2</sup> can't change his [spots](https://content.artofmanliness.com/uploads/2009/07/razorburn.jpg).
>  <sub><sup>1</sup> short for Leonard</sub>
>  <sub><sup>2</sup> another word for [partner, chum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pard)</sub>

Comment: Interesting... You're coming at this from the right angle, but the intended answer is something that fits a lot more naturally, I think.

Answer (score 8):

He didn't

> make a rash decision.

I.e.

> He decided against the rash and for the beard.

Answer (score 6):

Is it...

> Because this is the simplest solution and he is using Occam's razor?

Comment: The Question states that it has to deal with english proverbs.

Answer (score 4):

Is it because it's...

> [No Shave November](https://no-shave.org/)? Hahaha

Answer (score 3):

How about...

> Time is money.
>  Leonard, F. (1995).
>  
>  It's painful to optimize time/performance (talk to programmers) and probably to cut costs.

Answer (score 2):

Is the advice:

> Keep your chin up.

Comment: well this is a fun place to come and visit....

Comment: Just remember to keep your chin up.

Comment: @MattJameson Perhaps you'd have a better experience if you *explained* the reasoning behind your answer. As it is, it appears to just be a fairly random guess with a tenuous at best relationship to the question, which makes it appear to not that great of a guess. Funny content sometimes accumulate votes despite clearly being wrong or having other problems, but this answer doesn't seem to contain any humor, either.

Answer (score 2):

> Ask me no questions, I'll tell you no lies.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

> As you sow, so you shall reap

Comment: This isn't the intended answer. I don't really see how this is related to the riddle, to be honest.

Comment: Well I presumed it to be not this easy. But I was thinking that if Leonard gets razor burnt everytime then it might be this answer. Meaning that he gets the result according to the action taken by him.

Comment: The intended answer is wordplay, though.