# My First Mosquito Bite

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, english, language

Help! I just moved houses into an area with many mosquitoes. However, I haven't been outside all week - ever since the first bump appeared on my skin. What's happening to me? Is this some weird sort of allergy?

Edit: I'm not worried about the bump. I know that that comes with mosquito bites. Why can't I bring myself to go outside? It should be an easy thing to manage.

Hint:

> [Why will my friend have to grow his beard out?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74802/why-will-my-friend-have-to-grow-his-beard-out)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> 'Once bitten twice shy' which is a proverb like the hint and explains why you were hiding in your house after being bitten.

Comment: Based on the hint and tag, I think OP is looking for a little more wordplay than this.

Comment: @Dedwards sorry but there aren't too many tags that fit this. The wordplay was more so taking the English proverb too literally.

Answer (score 6):

You're clearly

> bugging out due to being bogged down by bugs in your bog causing bulges.

But I haven't figured out your diagnosis. Retrospectively, maybe you should have thought twice before going to

> beg a big bag of bog bugs.

Comment: Closest answer so far! I like the alliteration, but that's not the linguistic thing that I was after.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have been bitten

> not by a mosquito but by a *vampire*. Traditionally, vampires (1) also bite, (2) make their victims into vampires, and (3) can't tolerate sunlight. I'd have thought it wouldn't be hard to distinguish a mosquito bite from a vampire bite, though.

Comment: vampires and mosquitoes are also both blood suckers

Comment: I love the answer, it fits pretty well but my question has an answer based on linguistics.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the wordplay tag. OK.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure how to read these riddles, but maybe

> you are a snail (since you moved your house to a new area) and the swelling of the bump makes it impossible for you to crawl out of your house again.

After all, you are

> so small, that a mosquito bite leaves a comparatively big bump. So I advise to stay inside and wait for the swelling to abate.

Comment: I like your thinking, it reinterprets many of the words very well. However, I assure you that I am a human who may be taking something a bit too literally.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a

> goosebump? It's too cold outside. Even my friend is growing a beard to ward the cold.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. Remember to have a look at the tags to make sure your answer fits the question well. If you would like to learn more about this site (and earn your first badge) check out the tour from the link here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

> You have moved to Norway, where mosquitoes are known as stikkemygg. Therefore, you have been "stikke"'d and are stuck inside.

Comment: Mind the tags - one of them is 'english'